# The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it when removing a Label from the Canvas through a class's Destructor

Tags: c#, wpf, object

I have an object *IntervalLabel*, and when this object is removed, I cannot remove a Label from a Canvas when a Destructor is called,

This code makes sense to me but it causes an error on

```
commonParameters.mainCanvas.Children.Remove(intervalLabel);
```

The error is:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred 
in WindowsBase.dll
```

Additional information:

```
The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.
```

Additionally, this line of code does not cause an error,

```
intervalLabel.MouseLeftButtonDown -= new
System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventHandler(IntervalLabel_MouseDown);
```

How could I remove the label from the canvas through the Destructor?

```
class IntervalLabel
{
    private Label intervalLabel;

    public IntervalLabel(Canvas mainCanvas)
    {
        intervalLabel = new Label();
        mainCanvas.Children.Add(intervalLabel);
        intervalLabel.MouseLeftButtonDown += new System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventHandler(IntervalLabel_MouseDown);
    }

    private void IntervalLabel_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        //....
    }

    ~IntervalLabel()
    {
        intervalLabel.MouseLeftButtonDown -= new         System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventHandler(IntervalLabel_MouseDown);
        commonParameters.mainCanvas.Children.Remove(intervalLabel);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The finalizer (the thing that runs the `~ClassName()` function for you) runs on it's own thread so that is why you get the error, however you can't do the normal marshaling you would do because by the time the finializer called your function the context for the window may have been already destroyed.

You should not be putting operations like that in the finalizer, those should be put in the class'es `Dispose` function.

```
//Marking the class sealed so we don't need to deal with 
//    the "protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)" pattern.
sealed class IntervalLabel : IDisposable
{
    private Label intervalLabel;

    public IntervalLabel(Canvas mainCanvas)
    {
        intervalLabel = new Label();
        mainCanvas.Children.Add(intervalLabel);
        intervalLabel.MouseLeftButtonDown += new System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventHandler(IntervalLabel_MouseDown);
    }

    private void IntervalLabel_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        //....
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        intervalLabel.MouseLeftButtonDown -= new         System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventHandler(IntervalLabel_MouseDown);
        commonParameters.mainCanvas.Children.Remove(intervalLabel);
    }
}
```

You then will need to make sure to dispose of the object when you are done with it in whatever container you are using.

That being said, your design looks really weird. Something called `IntervalLabel` I would expect to derive from `Label` not contain a label inside it. Also if all you are doing is handling a mouse down event it does not look like this really needs to be a class at all and can be handeled in the XAML or in the codebehind of your Form.